# React-Select inside react-select

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I have created react select inside a react select menu list,
currently, the issue is that when I click the inner react select component the outer react select component menu list gets closed
how to fix this issue?

Main component

```
const CustomCalender = props => {
    return (
      <div>
        <Calendar props={props} />
      </div>
    );
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Select
      options={[{label:moment(),value:moment()}]}
        components={{ Option: CustomCalender }}
        styles={customStyles}
        maxMenuHeight="200"

      />
    </div>
```

Calendar component

```
                <Select
                     openMenuOnFocus={true}
                     openMenuOnClick={false}
                    className="basic-single"
                    classNamePrefix="select"
                    name="color"
                    options={this.state.colourOptions}/>
```

Comment: Can you please share some code snippets?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried stopping propagation

```
  <div>
    <Calendar props={props} />
  </div>
```

to:

```
  <div onBlur={e => e.stopPropagation()}>
    <Calendar props={props} />
  </div>
```